# Whats better when echoing strings

Tags: php, string, concatenation, echo

Im just curious as to what is the difference to these 3 types of strings.

```
echo "Hello my name is ".$name;

echo "Hello my name is $name";

echo "Hello my name is {$name}";
```

I know that in the third case its required over the 2nd when your using arrays with keys. For example, i know the following wont work.

```
echo "Hello my name is $data['name']";
```

You would need to do...

```
echo "Hello my name is{$data['name']}";
```

for it to work.

Does anyone have an explanation as to why this is?

Comment: `echo "Hello my name is $data[name]";` and `"Hello my name is ${data['name']};"` will also work.

Comment: Lookup http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php your find all you need to know in detail...inc Complex {curly} syntax descriptions

Comment: I suggest none of these! Use PHP templating where possible and remember to HTML-escape all text going out to the page. `Hello my name is <?php echo(htmlspecialchars($name)); ?>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People are giving their opinion, it's fine, but here are facts :

- Concatenation *is* faster
- The time gained by concatenating is trivial and not a good argument to justify its use
- In the end, the code does the same thing whatever method you choose

Basically, it does not matter how you do it, just choose your favorite and stick with it. If you work with a group of people, just use the same convention, for clean code's sakes.

Comment: ... and using double quotes with concatenation is pointless. Use single ones instead.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `"$foo"` and `"{$foo}"` is just a matter of parsing - the PHP parser only parses certain characters for variable names when interpolating, *unless* there are `{}` around it (in which case any characters are parsed).

Answer (score 0):

Well it is opinion of each person. I like

```
echo "Hello my name is $name";

echo "Hello my name is ".$data['name'];
```

> echo "Hello my name is $data['name']";
>   You would need to do...
>   echo "Hello my name is{$data['name']}";

you can do

> echo "Hello my name is $data[name]";

Answer (score 0):

I am strongly against concatenation, when simple variable interpolation in a string would suffice. Too much concatenation makes code unreadable.

```
"text $variable text"
```

for simple variables

```
"text {$array['key']} text"
```

for complex variables